# std::wcsstr not delivering expected result

Tags: c++, string, std

I'm trying to retrieve the name of an executable from the full file path like so:

```
//includes...

int pid = 1234;
HANDLE hProcess;
TCHAR proccessName[2048] = {};

//Get handle
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 
false, pid);

//Get filepath (e.g.: \Device\Harddisk\Users\Example\TheAppName.exe)
GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess, processName, sizeof(processName));

//Print just the .exe name (e.g.: Success, name is: TheAppName.exe)
std::wcout << "Success, name is: " << std::wcsstr(processName, L"\\");
```

The problem is that output is still something like

> Success, name is: \Device\Harddisk\Users\Example\TheAppName.exe

So `std::wcsstr` is not behaving as I expect, but after reading through docs I am still unsure what's wrong here.

Should the output not be:

> Success, name is: TheAppName.exe

Kind regards.

Comment: Given what [std::wccstr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcsstr) does, why do you expect the results to be `TheAppName.exe`?  Also, what does this have to do with the Windows API?  You could have just hardcoded a string and see what `wccstr` returns.

Comment: In addition, since you're using the Windows API, it is easier to use the [API functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to extract the name.

Comment: Ugh, somehow I confused `std::wcsrchr` with `std::wccstr`...it's been a long day. Sorry for the trouble.